# Xamarin.iOS: Binding project doesn't find types

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, binding

I followed the instructions to create a new binding project:

- Create the iOS binding project.
- Added a "Native Reference" via Visual Studio.
- Created APIDefinition.cs using Objective Sharpy.
- Add a new project for the app and try calling into the generated type.

But I get this error:

```
CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Foo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Sometimes, when building, I also get this warning (not always):

```
The referenced component 'Native References/Foo.framework' could not be found.
```

APIDefinition.cs only contains an interface, so I assume the concrete types are generated as part of the build? But somehow these aren't being generated.

And the warning about not finding the framework is bizarre since it's right there, and the reference was added by Visual Studio.

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: It looks like a `namespace missing` or referecen issue. Have you exactly followed [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=windows#create-a-xamarinios-binding-project) on how to Create a Xamarin.iOS Binding Project?

Comment: Did you, by any chance, find a solution?